# Receiving parameters with FromBody

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services

I have a webservice where I need to receive multiple parameters, one of which is a list.

This is the webservice method:

```
 [HttpPost("complete/{requestId}")]
 public IActionResult CompleteRequest([FromBody] RequestComplete requestComplete, int requestId)
 {

      if (requestId == 0)
      {
           return BadRequest();
      }

      if (requestComplete == null)
      {
           return BadRequest();
      }
      // execute code
 }
```

The RequestComplete class looks like this:

```
public class RequestComplete
{
    public int RequestId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string emailCC { get; set; }
    public string emailSubject { get; set; }
    public string calcsNeeded { get; set; }
    public string ssiComment { get; set; }
    public List<CompleteFileUpload> completeFiles { get; set; }

}
```

And the CompleteFileUpload class like this:

```
public class CompleteFileUpload
{
    public int RequestFileId { get; set; }
}
```

From PostMan I use a post body like this:

```
{
    "calcsNeeded" : "4",
    "completeFiles": {"RequestFileId": "384"},
    "emailCC" : "test@email.com",
    "emailSubject": "subject here",
    "ssiComment":"Thanks for your request."
}
```

My expectation is that the json posted by Postman will be formatted properly to be accepted by the CompleteRequest method. However, it does not.  If I remove the completeFiles section of the json, it runs fine.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of "completeFiles" in the JSON does not define a JSON array, it defines a single object.  That JSON would be valid if the definition was:

```
public class RequestComplete
{
    ...
    public CompleteFileUpload completeFiles { get; set; }
}
```

Try changing the JSON to:

```
{
    "calcsNeeded" : "4",
    "completeFiles": [ {"RequestFileId": "384"}, {"RequestFileId": "123"} ],
    "emailCC" : "test@email.com",
    "emailSubject": "subject here",
    "ssiComment":"Thanks for your request."
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Perfect.  I was missing the bracket that defined the array.